# Ubuntu 20.04 DT GUI incorrectly loading to VirtualBox instead of Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, virtualbox, gui

I've installed Ubuntu Server to VirtualBox and initially operates fine at the command level.  Host OS is Ubuntu DT 20.04 LTS.  Inexplicably, VirtualBox is now launching what appears to be the DT GUI version, although isn't fully accessible (allows login and activities access, but no other icon access).  Despite this, I can still SSH into the Host and Webserver from other devices and the server seems to still be working fine.  I've made no obvious changes that would have requested that this occur, so I'm unsure how to recover.

[VirtualBox window showing GUI instead of server command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXWk3.png)

If someone has experienced this issue, can you advise a correction method so I can revert to webserver command line in VirtualBox?

Comment: You probably installed some software that pulled in parts of a desktop. Check your `apt` logs in /var/log.  Look for the desktop managers `lightdm`, `gdm`, `sddm` etc.

Comment: Thanks and log notes 3 packages that were installed.  I suspected that one of the themes might have altered this, so removed all of them, for example using "apt-get remove --auto-remove humanity-icon-theme" followed by "apt-get purge humanity-icon-theme".  What additional changes might be required to completely remove and reinstate original command-line interface?

Comment: If installing some package pulled in the unwanted desktop stuff, uninstalling the package and then doing `sudo apt autoremove` would normally get rid of the stuff that was pulled in. You should see prompts about packages that are not longer required.

Comment: OK...went through to verify autoremove status for those that may have contributed to the issue.  Still some recently installed packages installed, but to my eye don't appear to have anything to do with this issue (perhaps I'm wrong).  The following is what I know....  any suggestions?

Autoremoved:
- samba
- humanity-icon-them
- light-themes
- gnome-tweaks
- virtualbox-guest-x11
- virtualbox-guest-dkms

Remaining recently installed:
- gnupg1
- nmap
- webmin
- net-tools
- software-properties-common    
- apt-transport-https

Comment: Why do you have icon themes installed for a server that isn't supposed to have a desktop? What pulled those in? When I do `aptitude why gnome-tweaks` it says `gnome` depends on it.  Is `gnome` installed, and if so, why? *Something* you installed pulled all this stuff in, and the answer is in your logs.

Comment: It's a great question.  Was simply attempting to adjust terminal color scheme, so was a mistake to load.  I have, however, hunted down the gnome reference and deleted "gnome-shell".  That did the trick.  Still on the Ubuntu Server learning curve, so really appreciate the help!!!!!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Takeaway: *look over that giant list of packages apt wants to install carefully!*